# Explain step by step how does Collections sort function in my code

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, collections

I am trying to figure out how to sort an ArrayList with different classes in it. (All have same superclass)

```
ArrayList<DessertItem> allDesserts = new ArrayList<DessertItem>() {
       {
           this.addAll(testingCandy);
           this.addAll(testingCookie);
           this.addAll(testingIceCream);
           this.addAll(testingSundae);
       }
   };
```

Once I add of the desserts in it, I managed to sort the desserts by calories using the code below.

```
Collections.sort(allDesserts, (dessert1, dessert2) -> dessert1.getCalories() - dessert2.getCalories());
```

However, I don't understand how exactly the code above sorted it. Can you walk me through it. (Mostly confused about the -> symbol)

The unsorted DessertList is:

```
Sour Patch Kids(Candy) has 999 Calories.
White Chocolate-flavored Peppermint-swirled Gumballs(Candy) has 775 Calories.
Macadamia Nut Cookies(Cookie) has 999 Calories.
Lemon Meringue Pie Macaroons(Cookie) has 1347 Calories.
```

After Sorting it becomes:

```
White Chocolate-flavored Peppermint-swirled Gumballs(Candy) has 775 Calories.
Sour Patch Kids(Candy) has 999 Calories.
Macadamia Nut Cookies(Cookie) has 999 Calories.
Lemon Meringue Pie Macaroons(Cookie) has 1347 Calories.
```

Answer (score 0):

`(dessert1, dessert2) -> dessert1.getCalories() - dessert2.getCalories()`

This notation `()->` is a lambda function. Collections.sort() takes in an array and a comparator function. In this case you are sorting based on the value of the method getCalories() which is probably the calories value.

When it does `dessert1.getCalories() - dessert2.getCalories()` negative means dessert1 belongs in front. Positive means dessert2 belongs in front.

Comment: You explained it really well! Thank you so much!